# "Discerning the Transmundane" - Can't place lexicon on receptacle

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've started the "Discerning the Transmundane" quest, went to the Tower of Mzark in Blackreach, then tried placing the lexicon on the receptacle. - Nothing happened. Reloaded the save, restarted the game, still nothing. The lexicon is on my inventory, but I can't place it.

It might be to the fact that I had somehow lost the attunement sphere, and had to `player.additem` it back. How to proceed with the quest?

If it matters, it's a level 27 Khajit, mostly one-handed and sneak.

Note: Completely sure I didn't drop the sphere. It just vanished from the inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up skipping the glitched part, directly giving myself the Runed Lexicon and updating quest state.

For that I used the [UESP page of the quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), which contains all quest states, and a link to the item ID. Then it was just a matter of running the commands:

```
player.additem 0003a3dd 1
setstage DA04 35
```

This only skips the inscribing stage, not the whole quest.